# 404 when reload URL in browser to defined router route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I uploaded my angular 4 app on a prod server, that works perfectly in local. On the server, I can visit pages by links but, if I try to write directly the url in browser, my page go to 404. I red that I could resolve by .htacces but it's not an apache server so I can't. Is there an only frontend solution to resolve problem?

Comment: What type of server are you running?

Comment: How do you render your application bundle ?

Comment: @SamyokNepal probably the answer is cloudflare, but If I can I have to do just frontend side

Comment: @Mium Sorry, can you make an example?

Comment: Cloudflare would be your hosting service--is your app just a frontend project? Or does it have a server as well? What server (eg. NodeJS, nginx, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The defaults client-side routing strategy used in Angular is the [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy).

If you are entering the `URL` manually you would need to configure your server to return the same page for all the different `URLs` that are requested from it. This strategy needs some co-operation from the server side.

> Is there a frontend solution to resolve the problem?

Use [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy)

> HashLocationStrategy uses the hash fragment part of the URL to store
>   state for the client, it easier to setup and doesn’t require any
>   co-operation from the server side but has the downside that it won’t
>   work with Angular Universal once that’s released.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) //enable hashbang approach
  ],
```

[`Location Strategies in Angular Router`](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/location-strategies-angular/)

[`Which strategy is best?`](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Comment: Thanks, you solution is pretty good and there is only a little problem: now I have to insert "#" to visit page. Is there solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope Mate there is not :( refer the link I have shared in the answer to understand the significance of # in hashbang Approach, Do not forget to mark the answer if it helped you to resolve your issue ;)

Comment: Yes I studies all your links, I hoped to find a javascript solution maybe to replace # with some else. Thank you anyway, is a good answer.